# Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, forms

I am new to Visual Studio 2010 C#. I already created a form. However, when I run the application there is an error occurred stating that `"Cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader'"`. Can someone tell me what happened and how can I resolve this issue? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It seems that you've created a `ColumnHeader` with the name `Name` on the form which in turn hides the form property `this.Name` which is a string... that's the only scenario I can imagine leading to the error from the provided screenshot.
IF my assumption is right you can resolve that by changing that line to `this.Name.Name = "ter";`

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you've created a ColumnHeader with the name "Name".
Please check if you have any controls with the name "Name".

Ex:-I had a DataGridView with column name "SrNo", "Name", "Age".
I was getting the same error. Why bcoz of "Name".

Solution: Rename the DataGridView's ColumnHeader "Name" to other say "Person" or any thing other than "Name".
But if you want to display the "Name" as Header text of DataGridView , you can keep the HeaderText as "Name".i.e.

Name: Person

HeaderText: Name

DataPropertyName: Person

Here DataPropertyName is optional. It is used if binding through collection as DataSource.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't want `.Text` instead of `.Name`?